# KDEConnect indicator not working with Pantheon desktop

Tags: desktop, pantheon, notifications

I really like Elementary OS 6 but I cannot get the KDEconnect indicator to work with the pantheon desktop.
If I open terminal, I can manually run up KDEconnect-settings and pair my android phone.
So the actual transfer of files works along with notifications from the phone all works.
But I can't reply to text messages (unless I use terminal and manually open KDEconnect-messaging).
It's like Pantheon desktop doesn't respond to standard applet calls from an app.
Is there an add in to Pantheon that will enable standard app notifications along with a working applet ?
Elementary OS 5.1 had this working (although the user had to jump through some hoops to get it to work)

thanks in advance.
Rich

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the instructions do work fine with Elementary OS 5.1 but not 6.
thanks for the tips though

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please follow the next steps:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

and enable on Pantheon with:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
# change OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;

sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/user/indicator-application.service /etc/systemd/user

systemctl --user start indicator-application.service
```

then reboot your computer, after that disable the second wifi icon with:

```
sudo nano /etc/wingpanel.d/ayatana.blacklist
# add "nm-applet"
```

My Weather Indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

Comment: thanks for your tip, however this does not work. If I try to install the winglet, I get :- Unable to locate package wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

Comment: You must add the ppa in order to have acces to wingpanel-indicator-ayatana. Could you please provide more info in order to help you better?,

Answer (score 0):

using the following instructions on a fresh install of OS 6 :-

sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

When I use the last command I get the error :-
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

If I try just :-
sudo apt install wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

I still get :-
E: Unable to locate package wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

I know the wingpanel-indicator-ayatana exists as under OS 5.1 it does install
I am wondering if the app only works on 5.1 and not 6

Thanks for the reply

Rich